# Find all solutions of the recurrence relation $a_n = 2a_{n−1} + 2n^2$

Tags: recurrence-relations

The associated homogeneous recurrence relation is $a_n = 2a_{n−1}$.
The characteristic equation is $r − 2 = 0$.
Since our characteristic root is $r = 2$, we know by Theorem 3 that 
$a_n = α_{2}^n$
Note that $F(n) = 2n^2$
 so we know by Theorem 6 that $s = 1$ and $1$ is not a root, the particular
solution is of the form 
$n = c · 2n^2$
 Plug into recurrence relation
$c.2n^2 = 2.c(n-1)^2 + 2n^2$

is this correct? if then can we discuss further step to get value of c and solutions?

Comment: Theorem 3? Theorem 6?

Comment: I guess you mean $a_n=\alpha 2^n$?

Comment: @Bernand yes that's  an=α2^n

Comment: It is $$a[n]=c_1 2^{n-1}-4 \left(\frac{n^2}{2}+2 n-2^n-3\ 2^{n+1}+2^{n+2}+3\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+2n^2$$

$$a_{n-1}=2a_{n-2}+2(n-1)^2$$

$$a_{n-2}=2a_{n-3}+2(n-2)^2$$

and so on, which tells you

$$a_n=2^2a_{n-2}+2^2(n-1)^2+2n^2$$

$$a_n=2^3a_{n-3}+2^3(n-2)^2+2^2(n-1)^2+2n^2$$

and so on down to

$$a_n=2^{n-1}a_1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^{i+1}(n-i)^2$$

Comment: i have to do it with linear homogeneous recurrence relations theorems

Comment: Without knowing precisely what each mentioned theorem is, that's difficult to do.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_m=b_m+c_0+c_1m+c_2m^2+\cdots$

$$2n^2=b_n+c_0+c_1n+c_2n^2+\cdots-2(b_{n-1}+c_0+c_1(n-1)+c_2(n-1)^2+\cdots)$$

Clearly $c_r=0$ for $r\ge3$

Consequently $$2n^2=b_n-2b_{n-1}+c_0(1-2)+c_1(n-2(n-1))+c_2(n^2-2(n-1)^2))$$

Compare the coefficients of$x^0,x^1,x^2$ so that $$b_n=2b_{n-1}=\cdots=2^rb_{n-r},r\le n-1$$

Answer (score -1):

..a_n= a_n(h) + a_n(particular soln)

```
 =c.(2)^n + { p2(n^2) + p1.n + p0 } (1)^n

 = c.(2)^n + p2(n^2) + p1.n + p0
```

Then we plug in the particular soln in the recurrence relation.. and get

(P2+2)n^2 +(p1-4p2)n + (2p2-2p1+p0)=0
And so for the eqn to be true for all n
P2+2 =0
P1-4p2 =0
2p2-2p1+p0=0

Solving we get p0=-12, p1=-8,p2=-2

So all solns are of the form
..a_n =c.(2)^n -2(n^2) -8n -12

This is the exact soution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).